# Can I use MIT licence plugins in my commercial web site?

Tags: licensing

If yes, what precautions should I take?

Comment: could u name those plugins? If u are using the plugins without license, for commercial use, that would be a lawsuit problem

Comment: [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: I dont see it as a commercial plugin. here is the link 'http://jqueryui.com/about'. they see it is available under GPL, so i guess you can use it

Comment: see also: [Can I use GPL, LGPL, MPL licensed packages with my application and make it closed source?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125606/can-i-use-gpl-lgpl-mpl-licensed-packages-with-my-application-and-make-it-close)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

With an MIT/X11-licensed product:

- you **CAN**:

  - re-use the code freely for your own use,
  - re-use the code freely for non-commercial AND commercial re-distribution, whether in source or binary form.
- you **CANNOT**:

  - claim authorship of the software,
  - thus you cannot attack the original author for using or publishing his original version.

So, yes, **you CAN use MIT/X11-licensed plug-ins in your commercial application**.

MIT/X11 is basically a simple contract that says:

- Person or company X created Y.
- Y belongs to X, but X is granting you the right to use it and do whatever you want with it.
- X cannot be held accountable for anything that goes downhill with what you do with Y.

Comment: If a part of my software uses the source code under MIT license and another part is written by me, how do I have to state that in my app? In each file or in the license "some of the files are taken from NNN (the original author) and changed by me"?

Comment: @Alex: again, IANAL, but I think the right way is to provide a file containing license information stating for which parts of your product it is used. But I'd also indeed had a comment where you use the code and give a reference to the author and source site, both for the the copyright claim but also to facilitate traceability if you need to look at that code later down the line.

Comment: @haylem Hi. Can you expand on the *you cannot claim authorship of the software*. How this relate to the entire product? So if I release a closed source product, that includes a MIT licensed piece of code, this product has two authors?

Comment: @this: Copyright and authorship are inalienable, and are not the same as a license. A license (like MIT) lays the terms for the use and distribution by a 3rd party. Copyright is implicit and inalienable. Though the MIT/X11 license gives you the right to reuse (in full or partly, modified or unaltered) a piece of sofware licensed that way, and to redistribute it (in both commercial or non-commercial forms, closed-source or open-source), you are not allowed to claim that that *specific* piece of code is yours. That being said, MIT is vague about *giving attribution*.

Comment: @this: The usual (both *correct* and *decent*) thing to do is to include, as part of your software, the terms of this license carrying the original author's name and copyright notice, and a note as to what it refers to. Depending on your software's form, this can be either in a LICENSE file, a "About..." dialog, or an information page, as long as it's bundled and visible with your software. (again, IANAL).

Comment: @haylem Thank you. In the meantime I have already opened a question about this. If you want you can post an answer there (No obligations to do so of course). http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/303288/120714

Answer (score 22):

The MIT license allows you to

> use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software

as long as the license text (copyright notice and disclaimer)

> shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

**Where does this license text have to appear?**

This text should appear where the software is used or copies are made. For example, you should keep the license text publicly visible in any JavaScript, or left as a comment in any PHP files. This is enough, even if the comment in the PHP file isn't publicly visible, because:

> > [If I use MIT-licensed software server-side, do I have to display the copyright notice or disclaimer?](http://www.tawesoft.co.uk/kb/article/mit-license-faq)
>
> Having MIT-licensed software work server-side (e.g. as a PHP script) to produce a HTML page is not redistributing the software, unless the program includes itself in its output.

Comment: But who checks if on your server you have license text?

Comment: Usually you're installing them via package manager, hence all files in the package are available. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 12):

The full text of the MIT License can be found [here](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

**I'm not a lawyer**, but it seems like you can

> deal in the Software without restriction

even so far as

> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software

provided that

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Again, **I'm not a lawyer**, but you might fulfill that condition via **comments in all pages or scripts** that use the MIT licensed plugin or **an Acknowledgments page**.

Answer (score 7):

Every opensource licence to date (MIT too, a BSD-spirited licence) allows you to **use the software on a commercial web site** (and that's **part of the reasons for the extreme OSS propagation** in latter years) with some **notable exception**. Those exceptions are:

- **Creative Commons'** [CC-BY-NC](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/) and [CC-BY-NC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/) (NC = Non Commercial)
- [Affero/GNU Affero/AGPL](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Affero_General_Public_License) (many names, same licence)

Comment: I don't think we can describe MIT/X11 as BSD-spirited: it's even less restrictive than BSD. They did appear at the same time and are both fairly permissive, though.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the point of the AGPL is to fix this particular loop-hole that allows the use of GPL-ed code in a closed-source service provider setting; which is exactly against what the GPL intended: being viral and forcing you to disclose your source if you use GPL code. (might be a bit off on that, never been quite on top of GPL-intricacies).